# Does VueJS provide some kind of redirect parameter whitelistening?

Tags: javascript, laravel, security, vue.js, vue-router

I have been using this code, it has working so far, but i'm a bit worried about the security aspect (like hacking redirect with example.com inside redirect query) of it, is it safe by default in VueJS?

### Login.vue:

```
try {
  await this.$store.dispatch("auth/login", this.form);
  this.$router.replace((this.$route.query as any).redirect || '/dashboard');
```

### Router.vue:

```
{
    path: "*",
    redirect: "/404"
},
{
    path: "/404",
    component: NotFound
},
```

### Router beforeResolve:

```
router.beforeResolve((to, from, next) => {
    let { permissions, shouldBeLoggedIn } = to.meta;

    if (typeof shouldBeLoggedIn !== "undefined") {
        const isLoggedIn = store.getters["auth/isLoggedIn"];

        if (isLoggedIn !== shouldBeLoggedIn) {
            router.push({ name: "Login", query: { redirect: to.path } });
            return;
        }
    }
    if (permissions) {
        if (!Array.isArray(permissions)) {
            permissions = [permissions];
        }

        for (const permission of permissions) {
            if (!store.getters["auth/hasPermission"](permission)) {
                next("/error/forbidden");
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    next();
```

Comment: Please define "safe"

Comment: @IVOGELOV like hacking redirect with http://example.com inside redirect query

Comment: As far as I know you can not `redirect` to another domain with Vue router - only to a path inside the current domain. But if you want to be 100% safe - simply do `this.$router.back()` instead of redirecting.